# Problems with finding the real solutions of equation

Tags: equation-solving, polynomials

I am trying to find real solutions of equation using Mathematica 8.0 but there is some problem I don't know how to explain.

For example, for the input

```
Solve[x^16 + x^3 + x + 1 == 0, x, Reals]
```

it gives

```
{{x -> -1}, {x -> Root[1 + #1 - #1^4 + #1^7 - #1^10 + #1^13 &, 1]}}
```

What does this mean?

Comment: Thanx to all for very detailed answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
eqn = x^16 + x^3 + x + 1 == 0;

sol = Solve[eqn, x, Reals]
```

> {{x -> -1},     {x -> Root[1 + #1 - #1^4 + #1^7 - 
>                #1^10 + #1^13 & , 1]}}

Verifying the solution

```
eqn /. sol // Simplify
```

> {True, True}

`Root[f, k]`represents the `exact k^th root` of the polynomial equation `f[x]==0`. Read the documentation for `Root`. The exact representation can be converted to an approximate real value using `N`

```
sol // N
```

> {{x -> -1.}, {x -> -0.683269}}

Verifying the approximate solution

```
eqn /. %
```

> {True, True}

or to keep the integer solution as an integer

```
sol /. y_Root :> N[y]
```

> {{x -> -1}, {x -> -0.683269}}

Comment: Does `ToRadicals[]` do anything productive on the `Root[]` expression?

Comment: @J. M. the order of this polynomial (order 13) is too high for `ToRadicals` to be able to convert the expression to the alternate representation. For much lower order polynomials it can be useful to those that prefer radical representations over the equivalent  `Root` representations.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Mathematica Documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html), `Root[f,k]` gives the $k^{th}$ root of the polynomial function `f[x]==0`. Try to see if you get the numerical values with the following:

```
sol=Solve[x^16+x^3+x+1==0,x,Reals]
N[sol]
```

Answer (score 0):

To see why this happened, we can firstly factor the polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}$.

```
Factor[x^16 + x^3 + x + 1]
```

> ```
> (1 + x) (1 - x + x^2) (1 + x - x^4 + x^7 - x^10 + x^13)
> ```

So -1 is a real root. The roots of `1 - x + x^2` are complex, now we consider the last polynomial. We need [*The Fundamental Theorem of Algebra*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra):

> Every $f\in\mathbb{R}[x]$ of odd degree has at least one root in $\mathbb{R}.$

The function [`CountRoots`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CountRoots.html) can give the number of real roots of a polynomial.

```
CountRoots[1 + x - x^4 + x^7 - x^10 + x^13, x]
```

> ```
> 1
> ```

The origin polynomial has two real roots, i.e. one is -1, the other is the real root of `1 + x - x^4 + x^7 - x^10 + x^13`. But because of the [*Galois Theory*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_theory) the polynomial of degree greater than 4 is not solvable by radical. In *Mathematica* the roots of a polynomial with degree $>4$ are usually expressed as [`Root[poly,k]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html). You can easily verify that when `k=1` the root is real.